# Facebook SDK 5 post with byline

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I've got the Facebook SDK working to auto post blog posts to my Facebook page, but I can't seem to get the post byline/author to appear.

If I share the URL directly to the page, the the article author will show up, but it doesn't with the SDK.

The docs show a variety of variables you can send, but no examples or much more information. The two options which look promising are `admin_creator` or `from`.

`admin_creator` says it requires an `object[]` with `id` and `name` but no examples to show what and how to pass this to the API. Anything I've tried doesn't work (such as profile ID and profile name), and the `from` I've tried passing a profile ID to no avail.

If anyone has done this can you help? Thanks!

SDK docs ref: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/post/

**Shared manually:**

[image: Shared manually]

**via SDK:**

[image: via SDK]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the metatag "Author" exist in your articles? Try to use the Object Debugger (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) and check if the "Author"'s name comes out. If not, the first thing is to understand why it doesn't appear.

**Option 1**: you missed the metatag in your code.

```
<meta name="author" content="Your name">
```

You can also add these metatags. The first one explicit the object type (article) while the second one links the author's name to an URL (like your FB's profile page):

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="article:author" content="yourlink.com"/>
```

**Option 2**: if you're already using all these metatags you may have some cache problem. Are you sure that the Facebook Spider's can read your metatags? Maybe are you exposing a version of the article that misses the metatags?

Comment: Yeh, author tags exist. If I copy and paste the same link into Facebook then it shows up, but if via SDK it didn't. I'll check to see if it's the cache though somehow

Comment: Does the object debugger find all metatags correctly?

Comment: Sorted it now, it was a mixture of caching and mismatched tags! -_-

Comment: Although now the share image doesn't show on an auto posted link, even though all the meta and OG data is correct.. :/